# Trying to make sense of Postgres' binary copy format in C#

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql

Consider the following text from the [PostgreSQL documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/interactive/sql-copy.html) on binary copying:

> 11-byte sequence PGCOPY\n\377\r\n\0 —
> note that the zero byte is a required
> part of the signature. (The signature
> is designed to allow easy
> identification of files that have been
> munged by a non-8-bit-clean transfer.
> This signature will be changed by
> end-of-line-translation filters,
> dropped zero bytes, dropped high bits,
> or parity changes.)

I can create the rest of the header ok, but what is meant by \377?  I thought the largest value you could have in a single byte was 256?

Also, in the example:

```
0000000   P   G   C   O   P   Y  \n 377  \r  \n  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0
0000020  \0  \0  \0  \0 003  \0  \0  \0 002   A   F  \0  \0  \0 013   A
0000040   F   G   H   A   N   I   S   T   A   N 377 377 377 377  \0 003
0000060  \0  \0  \0 002   A   L  \0  \0  \0 007   A   L   B   A   N   I
0000100   A 377 377 377 377  \0 003  \0  \0  \0 002   D   Z  \0  \0  \0
0000120 007   A   L   G   E   R   I   A 377 377 377 377  \0 003  \0  \0
0000140  \0 002   Z   M  \0  \0  \0 006   Z   A   M   B   I   A 377 377
0000160 377 377  \0 003  \0  \0  \0 002   Z   W  \0  \0  \0  \b   Z   I
0000200   M   B   A   B   W   E 377 377 377 377 377 377
```

What do those same 377 values represent, as I interprete the format, they shouldn't they be \0's?

If any one could help with the rest of the format, it would be appreciated.  I *could* cheat and use the CVS database copy, but with the number of rows I need to copy (in the millions) I understand the binary format would have many advantages in speed over the CVS one.

Comment: "but with the number of rows I need to copy (in the millions) I understand the binary format would have many advantages in speed over the CVS one." If you need to do this again, sure, it will. But if you only need to do it once, it's probably going to be faster to just run the slower dump than spend your time implementing the faster format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `\377` is octal - its decimal value is 255. Was there anything else about the format which was specifically confusing you?

Comment: that answers a LOT, especially as to why for example '013' was the length a the value, but was actually less than that in length.  This makes lots more sense.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you will not get any significant speedup by using the binary format. It has different benefits, but loading the data faster is not really one of them.

Just use standard csv and COPY command and you should be fine.